# Check fields attributes using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to find a fields in a class has a Obsolete attribute ,

What I have done is , but even thought the type has an obselete attribute its not found during iteration :

```
public bool Check(Type type)
{
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |  BindingFlags.Instance);

  foreach (var field in fields)
  { 
     if (field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), false) != null)
     {
        return true
     }
  }
}
```

EDIT :

```
class MyWorkflow: : WorkflowActivity
{
 [Obsolete("obselset")]
 public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

and using it like this , `Check(typeof(MyWorkflow))`

Comment: can you show the field declarations? and the type that you are passing to this method.

Comment: @Selman22 updated the question with usage example

Comment: You know that `[Obsolete]` shows up as warnings in build right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `ConnectionString` is nor `Field` and nor `NonPublic`.

You should correct `BindingFlags` and also, use `GetProperties` method to search for properties.

Try the following

```
public static bool Check(Type type)
{
  var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  return props.Any(p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), false) != null);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the ConnectionString  as part of the list fields using BindingFlags.NonPublic |  BindingFlags.Instance , and in the debugger i see the fields attribute are private. I do get the fields as "k_BackingField"

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler That's because under the hood c# is creating backing field for every auto implemented property (int this case `ConnectionString` property). Since you place attribute over Property, not over field, you should search for attribute among properties.